# Localhost Connection Error php

Tags: php, localhost

I am trying to run my website written in php. Suddenly, after almost nothing i changed, localhost shows me this error :

> Unable to load due to either poor internet connection or some CDN's aren't as responsive as we would like them to be. Try refreshing the page :D'

What kind of error is this?

Comment: "Almost nothing changed"?

Comment: Yeah i just removed console logs in javascript files and some html tags thats all

Comment: If you put them back, does everything work?

Comment: No, problem still remains. Even though i change internet source as well

Comment: Have the CDN's changed their addresses? Does your localhost have a connection to the Internet?

Comment: If you look in your network panel (I presume you're using a decent browser) does that show any external resources that aren't loading?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've either hidden JavaScript logs or specified that you only want to see Errors or Warnings. Open Chrome's Developer Tools and go to the Console tab. At the bottom you want to ensure that JavaScript is ticked and also ensure that you have "All", "Logs" or "Debug" selected.